# Como reescrever o URL apache com variável e depois usar outras variáveis no PHP?

Tags: php, apache, variáveis

Olá, não sei se o título da pergunta faz muito sentido, mas a dúvida é o seguinte:

Tenho esse código:

```
RewriteRule ^teste/([a-z]+)$ settings/php/teste.php?lib=$1
```

Ele cria um redirecionamento, mas quando tento adicionar variáveis pela URL não funciona:

**www.meusite.com/teste/{variável}?id={variável}**

Especificamente, tudo o que estiver depois do ponto de interrogação o PHP não reconhece como variável e por isso não consigo executar meu scrip. Há uma maneira melhor de configurar o apache para que eu possa reescrever o URL já adicionando uma variável padrão como se fosse um diretório, e em seguida utilizar as variáveis de um jeito normal? Ou o que vocês sugerem para que eu possa utilizar um URL dessa forma?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil passar `/teste/{variável}/id/{variável}` e tratar isso no arquivo `teste.php`?

Comment: Sim, mas eu gostaria de utilizar dessa maneira que eu postei, caso eu não encontre a solução para esse problema, eu serei obrigado a fazer isso...

Comment: E também, terão vários parâmetros não só a id, por isso complica mais..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece falta a flag *QSA* na sua rota.

```
RewriteRule ^teste/([a-z]+)$ settings/php/teste.php?lib=$1 [QSA]
```

---

Veja a [DOC](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]
>
> With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped
>   to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same
>   request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing
>   query string will be discarded

Comment: Nossa cara mt obg, salvou minha vida!!